# How to handle chained dependencies in Sass projects with npm?

Tags: npm, sass

I have two Sass projects which I'm working on. Let's call them ProjectBase and ProjectExtended. ProjectExtended depends on ProjectBase, and the ProjectBase depends on a third party node module, namely Bootstrap.

ProjectBase should be independent but also work when used as a dependency.

ProjectBase has this include in it's Sass file:

`@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

ProjectExtended then has this include:

`@import '../node_modules/ProjectBase/scss/ProjectBase'`;

ProjectBase can build this without issues after running `npm install` because the included file is in that path under `node_modules`.

The problem arises in ProjectExtended because now after running `npm install`, the Bootstrap source is not in the same relative location anymore from the point of view of ProjectBase:

`-node_modules/
|--bootstrap
|--ProjectBase`

As you see in this case Bootstrap is suddenly a sibling instead of a dependency like so:

`-node_modules/
|--bootstrap
|--ProjectBase
   |--node_modules
      |--bootstrap`

As a workaround, I manually go into `node_modules/ProjectBase` and then run `npm install` in there, which installs those dependencies a second time under that folder.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by providing [custom importer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental) to `node-sass`. I have [simple implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-importer) of such importer that you can try to use, it will allow you to configure all necessary paths and rules to resolve imports inside your `.scss` files.

In your case configuration may look like `{roots: ['node_modules','../node_modules']}` if I understand your directories structure properly.